# Populating a textbox based on the ID of another selected input

Tags: php, mysql

Having a hard time populating a textbox with the ID of a selected value from another selectbox.

Here's my code in the form currently:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="AssetType" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Asset Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?php
            require 'includes/connection.php';
            $sql = "SELECT AssetType FROM tblAssetsType";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        ?>
        <select name="assettype">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an Asset Type</option>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
            <option><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="AssetTypeID" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Asset Type ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?php
            require 'includes/connection.php';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAssetsType WHERE AssetTypeID = 1";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo $row["AssetTypeID"];
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above works well and does pull the correct data back when I manually point it to the ID #.  What I can't seem to figure now is how to replace that value with the value that matches the ID of the selected Asset Type.

So in short, what I need is:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="AssetTypeID" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Asset Type ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?php
            require 'includes/connection.php';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAssetsType WHERE AssetTypeID = ID of selected option below";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<input type="text" name="id" value="'. Unknown Parameter . '">';
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

If there is a better way, or if I'm not understanding any direction is greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: Is the Unknown Parameter in `echo '<input type="text" name="id" value="'. Unknown Parameter . '">'` a result value from your query? Is that what you're looking to populate?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's not.  The **Unknown Parameter** is actually the **ID#** that is associated with the **AssetType** above in the selectbox.  That is what I can't figure out how to capture to display in the echo.

Comment: So basically If I select **AssetType option 2**, then **AssetTypeID Textbox** should be populated with the corresponding **ID#** of that selected option, make sense.

Comment: You can't do that with PHP then. From what I understand you are trying to manipulate the DOM with server side language. You need to use javascript of its libraries like jquery for that

Comment: Ok, I've seen that.  using the onchange or something like that.  thanks for your help, I'll research that and see how I can apply it.

Comment: Check out Jquery: https://api.jquery.com/select/